# Python Selenium Exception Handling Distorting Dataset?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This code runs fine. In the output dataset, brand, item, and inci_name are all perfect. At a glance, function looks good, too. However, the rest of the values are jumbled up. The code is also not consistently writing 'null' in cells where it should be.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


data = []

for y in range(1,101):
    website = f'https://www.knowde.com/b/markets-personal-care/products/{y}'
    path = '/Users/kdavid3mbp/Python/chrome_driver64/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.get(website)

    for x in range(1,37):
        products = driver.find_elements('xpath', f'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[{x}]')

        for product in products:
            brand = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[1]').text
            item = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[2]').text
            inci_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[2]').text
            try:
                ingredient_origin = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[3]/span[2]').text
            except:
                ingredient_origin = 'null'
            try:
                function = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
            except:
                function = 'null'
            try:
                benefit_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except: 
                benefit_claims = 'null'
            try:
                description = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[3]').text
            except:
                description = 'null'
            try:
                labeling_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except:
                labeling_claims = 'null'
            try:
                compliance = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
            except:
                compliance = 'null'
            try:
                hlb_value = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except:
                hlb_value = 'null'                
            try:
                end_uses = product.find_element('xpath', '/a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except:
                end_uses = 'null'
            try:
                cas_no = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except:
                cas_no = 'null'
            try:
                chemical_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
            except:
                chemical_name = 'null'
            try:
                synonyms = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
            except:
                synonyms = 'null'
            try:
                chemical_family = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except:
                chemical_family = 'null'
            try:
                features = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[7]/span[2]').text
            except:
                features = 'null'
            try:
                grade = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except:
                grade = 'null'

        dict = {
            'brand': brand,
            'item': item,
            'inci_name': inci_name,
            'function': function,
            'description': description,
            'ingredient_origin': ingredient_origin,
            'benefit_claims': benefit_claims,
            'labeling_claims': labeling_claims,
            'compliance': compliance,
            'hlb_value': hlb_value,
            'end_uses': end_uses,
            'cas_no': cas_no,
            'chemical_name': chemical_name,
            'synonyms': synonyms,
            'chemical_family': chemical_family,
            'features': features,
            'grade': grade
        }
        
        data.append(dict)
        print('Saving: ', dict['brand'])


# Closes driver once for loop is completed
driver.quit()
```

At first, I thought the issue might be with how I was dealing with exception handling. I created a new file where I imported

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Then, for each element where I knew the element was not consistently present throughout the website, I added NoSuchElementException as follows

```
try:
    ingredient_origin = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[3]/span[2]').text
except NoSuchElementException:
    ingredient_origin = 'null'
```

I ran the code again and the dataset did not change. [Here's the first 100 rows](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UqTghhpmvpfPrZhAjLHzvoVsYGtLWEeiGjpouLtT15o/edit?usp=sharing) of the dataset.

What's going on here? Thank you!

Comment: Be careful; a bare `except:` statement (rather than `except NoSuchElementException`) will hide a variety of errors from you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I mention in the post, I created a separate code that used this but the resulting dataset was identical.

Answer (score 0):

To download the product data you can use their pagination Ajax API call (thus, using only `requests`):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.knowde.com/b/_next/data/lIiYf_6sxqVK3gpFdQVF0/markets-personal-care/products/{page}.json?l2-category=markets-personal-care&page={page}'

all_data = []
for page in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    print(f'{page=}')
    data = requests.get(url.format(page=page)).json()
    for r in data['pageProps']['browsePage']['records']:
        all_data.append({
            'name': r['name'],
            'brand': r['brandName'],
            'company': r['companyName'],
            **{
                f"characteristics_{ch['name']}": ','.join(ch['values'])
                for ch in r['characteristics']
            },
            **{
                f"summary_{ch['name']}": ','.join(ch['values'])
                for ch in r['summary']
            }

        })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

This saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to all of this. Can you provide a resource where I can learn more about leveraging these APIs and writing code similar to what you've provided here?

Comment: @kdavid3891 The data you see on the page must be *living* somewhere. Usually, it's embedded within the page (in HTML tags or in Json form) or (in this case) the page is doing dynamic requests to load more data. When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab and start scrolling down, you will see the pagination URLs there.